# How to read columns of type doubles in MDB files in node?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, ms-access, odbc

I'm querying some MDB files in nodejs on linux using [MDBTools](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/), [unixodbc](http://www.unixodbc.org/) and the [node odbc](https://npmjs.org/package/odbc) package.

Using this code

```
db.query("select my_str_col, my_dbl_col from my_table", function (err, rows) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(rows);
    db.close();
});
```

I can query the `my_str_col` string column but I can't decipher the `my_dbl_col` `Double` column, I get something like this :

```
[ { my_str_col: 'bla',     my_dbl_col: '{\u0014�Gai�@' },
  { my_str_col: 'bla bla', my_dbl_col: '' },
  { my_str_col: 'bla', my_dbl_col: '�G�z\u0014NF@' } ]
```

All not empty strings are 7 or 8 bytes but what bothers me most is the second row of this example where I get an empty string while I know there is a not null number in the MDB : it means I can't try to build the numbers from the string bytes.

So, how can I read numbers of type `Double` in a MDB file in node on linux ?

I precise that

- a tool like MDBViewer (using MDBTools) correctly reads those numbers
- JavaScript numbers will be precise enough for me : those numbers would all fit in float32
- I can't apply lengthy conversions on the MDB files : I must make fast queries on a few hundred frequently changed files...
- a solution in which I can't really issue queries but which lets me read the whole table would be acceptable too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I couldn't get node-odbc to correctly decipher numbers, I wrote a function calling [mdb-export](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/mdb_export) (which is very fast) and reading the whole table.

```
var fs   = require("fs"),
    spawn  = require('child_process').spawn,
    byline = require('byline'); // npm install byline   

// Streaming reading of choosen columns in a table in a MDB file. 
// parameters :
//   args :
//     path : mdb file complete path
//     table : name of the table
//     columns : names of the desired columns
//   read : a callback accepting a row (an array of strings)
//   done : an optional callback called when everything is finished with an error code or 0 as argument
function queryMdbFile(args, read, done) {
    var cmd = spawn('/usr/bin/mdb-export', [args.path, args.table]);
    var rowIndex = 0, colIndexes;
    byline(cmd.stdout).on('data', function (line) {
        var cells = line.toString().split(',');
        if (!rowIndex++) { // first line, let's find the col indexes
            var lc = function(s){ return s.toLowerCase() };
            colIndexes = args.columns.map(lc).map(function(name) {
                return cells.map(lc).indexOf(name);
            });
        } else { // other lines, let's give to the callback the required cells
            read(colIndexes.map(function(index){ return ~index ? cells[index] : null }));
        }
    });
    cmd.on('exit', function (code) {
        if (done) done(code);
    });
}
```

Here's an example in which I build an array with all rows of the question's example :

```
var rows = [];
queryMdbFile({
    path: "mydatabase.MDB",
    table: 'my_table',
    columns : ['my_str_col', 'my_dbl_col']
},function(row) {
    rows.push(row);
},function(errorCode) {
    console.log(errorCode ? ('error:'+errorCode) : 'done');
});
```

Everything is read as strings but easy to parse :

```
[ ['bla',     '1324'  ],
  ['bla bla', '332e+5'],
  ['bla',     '43138' ] ]
```

Surprisingly enough, this is faster than querying using node-odbc and linuxodbc.

Comment: Users wanting to apply this to files mounted using Samba might be interested by this related question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/339354/cant-alloc-filename-when-executing-mdb-export-on-a-mounted-file/339602?noredirect=1#comment433332_339602